# checking processes before run

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Hi I am trying to make a script which checks 3 files before run. If they are running or not. What is wrong with my code?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! $(pgrep -f a1.php) ]];  //check if any pid number returned if yes close and exit this shell script    
    exit 1
if [[ ! $(pgrep -f a2.php) ]];  //check if any pid number returned if yes close and exit this shell script 
    exit 1
if [[ ! $(pgrep -f a3.txt) ]];  //check if any pid number returned if yes close and exit this shell script  
    exit 1
else
    php -f a.php; php -f b.php; sh -e a3.txt   //3 files is not running now we run these process one by one
fi
```

Comment: You are missing a then after the if conditions

Comment: Bash doesn't use // comments, only #

Comment: Also, quotes are missing around `$(...)`, as well as `else` or `elif` or `fi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not using the right format for `if` in bash, in particular you have missed out `then` and `fi`.
2. `$()` subshell is possibly not doing what you think.  It returns the stdout of the command inside, not the exit code (which is normally what you test against).  Either `$(pgrep -c -f a1.php) -gt 0` using the `-c` flag to return the number of matching processes, or `pgrep -f a1.php > /dev/null` using the exit code would be better.

   `[[ ! $(pgrep -f a1.php) ]]` might work in this case, but `[[ $(pgrep -f a1.php) ]]` would fail if more than one process matched, so it is fragile.

Try,

```
if [[ $(pgrep -c -f a1.php) -gt 0 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
if [[ $(pgrep -c -f a2.php) -gt 0 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
if [[ $(pgrep -c -f a3.txt) -gt 0 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi

php -f a.php; php -f b.php; sh -e a3.txt
```

OR ALTERNATIVELY

```
pgrep -f a1.php > /dev/null && exit 1
pgrep -f a2.php > /dev/null && exit 1
pgrep -f a3.php > /dev/null && exit 1

php -f a.php; php -f b.php; sh -e a3.txt
```

See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html for more information on the if statement.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer and link it works perfectly.